# Need to build a quuerly groupby

Tags: mysql, group-by, where-clause

Hi I am trying to build a query not getting my desired result please help me.

Here is my table:

```
SELECT count(*)  
FROM  
    t_user_segment  
WHERE  
    updatedOn  
BETWEEN '2015-11-03 00:00:00' AND '2015-11-03 23:59:59'
```

i want to get data here from here of field updatedon from last 5days to  current date.

Comment: So if you want count per day then just add `SELECT count(*) as cnt, date(updatedOn) as updatedOnDate FROM t_user_segment WHERE updatedOn BETWEEN '2015-11-03 00:00:00' AND '2015-11-03 23:59:59' group by updatedOnDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below answer if it useful
SELECT count(*) as cnt, date(updatedOn) as updatedOnDate FROM t_user_segment
WHERE updatedOnDate >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 5 DAY) group by updatedOnDate;